# an login example using spring mvc,hibernate

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

please give me an example without using maven and spring security but using hibernate annotation and spring mvc with folder structure.

Because I am new to this topic.

Every example not having folder structure or some thing.
I want only proper simple login using spring mvc hibernate.

Comment: i used this sample but don't have folder structure and con't download source code also  http://www.roseindia.net/spring/spring4/login-form-using-spring-mvc-and-hibernate.shtml

Comment: This question isn't fit for SO -> `Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. ` Edit it to specify the exact problem you face so that we can help  you else it will be flagged for closure.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.beingjavaguys.com/2013/03/spring-hibernate-integration-tutorial.html

First you complete this project after complete understanding you can proceed for a login form.